# Using amazon RDS from google app engine. please help !

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-rds

I have some queries.

1. By default Google appengine (cloud based deployment platform) does not support mysql or any database for that matter. So we thought of using Amazon RDS as a option (Since it is in cloud.). After reading the documentations, i understood that amazon exposes the web services and provides API s for basic operations like creating a DB instance etc. But i am not sure whether it provides APIs for CRUD operations.? So that programatically i should configure amazon RDS and perform CRUD operations in it. Please answer.
2. Can i write a web service which is similar to amazon WS to perform CRUD operations in amazon RDS? is it feasible? please answer my questions ASAP.

Comment: AppEngine does not support _relational_ databases. But it does support a database - the datastore.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon RDS exposes MySQL databases using the standard MySQL protocol. App Engine can only make outgoing connections over HTTP, so it won't be possible to connect directly to RDS from App engine. You certainly could write a web service such as you describe, but you'd need to run it on a separate server (such as an EC2 instance), and you'd need to write your own interface for accessing the database on the client end, separate from the MySQL libraries.

Note that we're planning to introduce support for relational databases in the future with [App Engine for Business](http://code.google.com/appengine/business/).

Comment: When is the usable version of the App Engine for business expected. Because of performing this operation previously described in the post, we can purchase the App engine for business,

Comment: We don't have an ETA for general availability yet. You can sign up for the trusted tester scheme from the signup page linked from the AE4B page.

Comment: Is this still true given the existence of the [socket api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/) ?

Answer (score 2):

I have never used them but [RdbHost](https://www.rdbhost.com/indexC.html) was built (so it seems) for this reason. You can make your SQL calls over https. This will be slower though.